# Tomar el nombre de una pagina y llevarlo a otra

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, backend

necesito de su ayuda para este detalle yo tengo mi pagina principal que tiene 4 opciones a elegir
cada una de estas me lleva a una ruta de directorio diferente

Opcion 1 ----> Carpeta 1

Opcion 2 ----> Carpeta 2

Opcion 3 ----> Carpeta 3

Opcion 4 ----> Carpeta 4

Ahora lo que pasa es que estas Opciones me llevan a la pagina que utiliza html por defecto osea la indexof

Lo que necesito es que si doy click en la Opcion 1 ese nombre se pase a la Indexof y me lo muestre como un titulo, si yo doy click en la Opcion 2 me de el nombre de esa opcion.Osea en la misma pagina pero que solo cambie el nombre del titulo.

No se exista alguna funcion de JS que realize esto.
Investigando un poco encontre que utilizando window location href se pueden pasar parámetros de una pagina a otra pero he encontrado a alguien que lo explique bien espero puedan ayudarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es mi pagina origen:**

```
<div id="Titulos">
    <a id="o1">Opcion 1</a>
    <a id="o2">Opcion 2</a>
    <a id="o3">Opcion 3</a>
    <a id="o4">Opcion 4</a>
  </div>
```

Esta es mi pagina destino

```
 <div class="ruta-div">
        <a id="ruta">RUTA</a>
       </div>
```

Donde dice ruta es donde quiero que se muestra la Opcion a la cual le di click.
Gracias y espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Hola, intentaste mandar esos datos mediante `GET` de `php`? lo único que el link te va a quedar medio extraño ejemplo. `/carpeta1?valor="titulo"`, si te interesa te redacto mejor la respuesta.

Comment: Osea, quieres modificar el titulo de tus otras paginas en base al contenido de tu etiqueta `<a>`?, y porque no simplemente le pones de primeras ese titulo a las otras paginas? o porque desearias cambiarlo realmente?, no se si con `indexOf` a lo que te refieres es a la pagina principal.

Comment: Una sugerencia mas elaborada, seria preparar una clase ruteadora con PHP, y luego con un .htaccess, todas las peticiones sean ruteadas a tu indexOf, en tu clase ruteadora descomponer la URL de llamada y de ahi obtener el valor del titulo de pagina